# Redirect to checkout instead of cart

Tags: shopping-cart, redirect

I have a cart icon in the top navigation bar and when clicked, the page will redirect to checkout instead of the shopping cart page.

My reason is, the shopping cart page contains a table that displays the items added by the customer while the checkout page has the form for billing address and again, the table for displaying the items that are added to cart.

So I came up with the decision to just redirect to checkout instead of cart page to improve convenience and its only redundant if customer's will go to cart page to see their items and then checkout where they can see it also.

**Is it a good decision? If not, what is the reason?**

Comment: What's the question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By my experience:

**If you have a items list with option to remove products and change quantity showing on mouseover the basket shortcut and your product is not complex like to sell roof you could successfully add a checkout button highlighted like this example below.**

On **simple product** the users normally don't need to much change and don't need to think a lot to buy. Maybe you could increase impulse buying.

Otherwise, on **complex products** the user normally thinks a lot, add and remove items, think more because the average order value tends to be bigger. In these cases send basket by email or save basket could be a good option.

[image]

And considering the icon suggested by @Daniil, I already make a research about it and discovered that in the UK is more familiar to the users to use a **BASKET** icon and on the USA the **CART**. Now depending on your region. And please use simple icons not complex to understand that the users will thank you.

If your e-commerce is not so big please try it because on big e-commerce is difficult to approve big changes like this. Any error could result in losing money.

But never accept no as an answer, everything should be tested to be 100% right. And if you try it please share with us the results, I'm curious.

Answer (score 0):

I would say no. Before checking out, a user wants to review the items they purchased in their basket. Traditionally, this is presented before a checkout screen.

Whilst a cart is also normally used to show checkout, you should have a clear cart icon next to it, for example:

[image: shopping bag]

As other websites use the cart icon for basket, you could use a more clearer icon for checkout, like a till icon:

[image: till]

Comment: "_Before checking out, a user wants to review the items they purchased in their basket._" I would call that an over-generalisation. Probably the majority of my online  purchases have been for only one item, and having to go through a "_here's what you're about to buy_" page before actually being able to checkout isn't really necessary and can be borderline annoying... especially if, as in the OP's case, the checkout page includes a list of item(s) being bought.